# Why does bond energy not vary with position?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

Consider the formation of a hydrogen bond:
$$\ce{H + H -> H2}$$
The $\Delta H$ is $\pu{-436 kJ mol-1}$, so we can equally write the equation as: $$\ce{H + H -> H2 + \pu{436 kJ}}$$

But depending on the differences in position between the hydrogen atoms, there will be a different force of attraction between each other by Coulomb's law. **So the potential energy will be larger the farther away the hydrogen atoms are from each other; thus, more energy would need to be released to form a covalent bond**. So how does it always release $\pu{436 kJ}$ of energy when forming an $\ce{H2}$ bond if the energy must vary depending on initial position?

Comment: Of course while the *strict* definition of the bond energy is based on infinite separation, the shape of the potential energy surface gets very flat very quickly. So the difference in energy between say a separation of 10 bond lengths and 5 bond lengths as a starting point might be so small it is inside the error bars of the value.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good point, and precisely because of this, bond dissociation energies (in fact, *any kind of reaction energy or enthalpy*) are defined such that different reactants are infinitely separated from each other. This includes, for example, the two hydrogen atoms on the left-hand side of

$$\ce{H + H -> H2}.$$

This means that there are no Coulombic forces between the hydrogen atoms (or, to be precise, no forces between the constituent particles of different hydrogen atoms).

You may have seen a diagram such as the one in this answer by porphyrin: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/57157/16683

The infinite separation corresponds to the far right end of the diagram (where the energy $E = 0$), and the bond corresponds to the bottom of the well. That is why the bond dissociation energy is equal to the depth of the well.*

In general, if you have something like

$$\ce{A + B -> C + D}$$

what this means is that $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ are at infinite separation, and then you bring them together, they react to form $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{D}$, and you infinitely separate the products again.

---

* (Neglecting zero-point energy.)